# Optimizing in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, optimization

Suppose I have a tensorflow graph implementing a classification model:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape)
# [insert mdoel here]
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=..., units=num_labels, activation=None)
```

Now suppose I want to optimize over the inputs using the Adam optimizer.

For instance, in order to find targeted adversarial examples, I would declare a variable to optimize over (initialized at some sample during execution), specify a target class different from the true class, compute the cross-entropy and minimize it.

```
var_to_optimize = tf.Variable(np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.float32))
tgt_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[num_labels])
xent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=tgt_label, logits=logits)
```

I would then like to minimize the cross-entropy by perturbing the inputs

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(xent, var_list=[var_to_optimize])
```

However, xent requires that I feed values for the input placeholder x. How do I link the model's logits with var_to_optimize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question I was trying to answer is essentially the following: how can one create two separate optimization procedures on the same tensorflow graph?

The tutorial in the following link describes how to do this: a tensorflow graph is defined that trains a neural network and then adds random noise (uniform across samples) optimized to induce misclassification of most samples.

https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/12_Adversarial_Noise_MNIST.ipynb